# Unable to install service_identity module

Tags: python, pip, python-module

When I try the command `pip install service_identity` It returns with the following error.

```
Downloading/unpacking service-identity
  Downloading service_identity-14.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1259, in prepare_files
    )[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried with sudo also, but same error returned. How to solve this?

Comment: what version of pip are you using?

Comment: just installed on my machine successfully. Which version of python, pip you are using ?

Comment: I have just successfully installed it with `easy_install` command. Thank you all

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus, there is no reason at all why pip would not work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry I have no idea why :(

Comment: I would recommend updating pip